# Wordpress include('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php')

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a website with a simple login. A user enters a username and password and clicks the login button which sends POST data to a separate php file which then accesses and checks the input from the database. This process works fine.

However, I have some code that displays the most recent post from my wordpress blog that is in the same server location (/public_html). When I add  include('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php') it breaks my login system stating that the username and password for the database -the details used to access it- (not the user input) is wrong. I've made sure I am not inputting the wrong credentials. Any ideas why this may occur?

My code for login is as follows:

```
//if user visits page first time - no status is set
if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) || $_SESSION['status'] == NULL ) {

$login = "<h1> Login <small style='color:#E54FBF'> enter your credentials </small></h1>
    <p>
        <label for='memberid'>Member ID: </label>
        <input type='text' name='memberid' required />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='memberpassword'>Password: </label>
        <input type='password' name='memberpassword' required />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type='submit' id='submit2' value='Login' name='submit2' />
    </p>";
```

This code is the login part. Then on submit this is called:

```
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['memberid']) && !empty($_POST['memberpassword'])) {

$response = $membership->validate_user($_POST['memberid'], $_POST['memberpassword']); }
```

As I stated, the code works flawlessly without the include. What could be the issue? I receive errors that the username and password for accessing the database (not the user entered details) are incorrect - they aren't! I guess somewhere they are being reassigned but I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show the exact error message, along with the line number of the file, and the code that appears at and around that line. My guess is both your code and wordpress's code contain variables with the same name and therefor one is overwritting the other.

Comment: @Steve That can not happen, because WP is storing the information for the connection in constants.

Comment: How about including `wp-config.php` instead to have access to WP core only?

Comment: @lolka_bolka sure, but if OPs db name variable is called something unfortunate like `$post` then there will be issues!! Really we are just guessing until we see some code

Comment: Make sure that in your code you don't use the same variable names to connect to your database that might be overwritten at some point by Wordpress.

You can easily test this by doing a var_dump on each of your connection variables, ex. $host, $user, $pass, $db_name immediately after including wp-header.php and checking their integrity.

Comment: Thanks guys - Steve hit the nail on the head. It was caused because of variable name conflicts! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys - Steve hit the nail on the head. It was caused because of variable name conflicts! Cheers!